# Decorator is not working on a view function in Django

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, python-decorators

I have two model class as **Shopkeeper** and **Customer** which have onetoone key from **User Model**. Now I have a view as

```
@require_customer()
def add_to_wishlist(request, pk):
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
    customer = Customer.objects.get(user=request.user)
    wl = WishListProduct(product=product, customer=customer)
    wl.save()
    return HttpResponse("Added to Wish List !")
```

And the **Decorator** is as follow:

```
def require_customer(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url='/login/'):
    def is_customer(u):
        return Customer.objects.filter(user=u).exists()
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_authenticated and is_customer, login_url=login_url,
    redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name)
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    else:
        return actual_decorator
```

Now if I am logged in as Shopkeeper and I call this view with following url:

```
path('products/<pk>/addToCart/', views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),
```

It should redirect to Login page but instead it give me an error as

```
OnlineShops.models.DoesNotExist: Customer matching query does not exist.
```

Can you help me out finding the bug here?

Comment: Could you please fix the indentation in your code?

Comment: @EugenePrimako indentation is fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your lambda function

```
lambda u: u.is_authenticated and is_customer
```

should look like

```
lambda u: u.is_authenticated and is_customer(u)
```

This typo might allow not authenticated users to get into your view instead of redirecting them to Login page.

If it doesn't solve the problem - please give us the whole traceback, not only the exception text.